# Creating a new column in R with help of 3 existing columns

Tags: r

Want to create a new column "non_coded" using existing  3 columns-  allele_2 , allele_1 and A1

the conditions I want satisfied are :

```
if allele_2 == A1 then non_coded = allele_1 

if allele_2 != A1 then non_coded = allele_2
```

Thanks in advance,

Rad

## OK This is what the data looks like:

```
SNPID          chrom STRAND IMPUTED allele_2 allele_1     MAF CALL_RATE HET_RATE
1  rs1000000    12      +       Y        A        G 0.12160   1.00000   0.2146
2 rs10000009     4      +       Y        G        A 0.07888   0.99762   0.1386

     HWP    RSQ  PHYS_POS A1 M1_FRQ M1_INFO M1_BETA  M1_SE    M1_P
1 1.0000 0.9817 125456933  A 0.1173  0.9452 -0.0113 0.0528 0.83090
2 0.1164 0.8354  71083542  A 0.9048  0.9017 -0.0097 0.0593 0.87000
```

## The code I tried:

```
Hy_MVA$non_coded <- ifelse(Hy_MVA$allele_2 == Hy_MVA$A1, Hy_MVA$allele_1, Hy_MVA$allele_2)
```

result:

```
 SNPID       chrom STRAND IMPUTED allele_2 allele_1     MAF CALL_RATE HET_RATE
1  rs1000000    12    +       Y        A        G 0.12160   1.00000   0.2146
2 rs10000009     4    +       Y        G        A 0.07888   0.99762   0.1386

     HWP    RSQ  PHYS_POS A1 M1_FRQ M1_INFO M1_BETA  M1_SE    M1_P non_coded
1 1.0000 0.9817 125456933  A 0.1173  0.9452 -0.0113 0.0528 0.83090         3
2 0.1164 0.8354  71083542  A 0.9048  0.9017 -0.0097 0.0593 0.87000         3
```

What I want:

```
SNPID        chrom STRAND IMPUTED allele_2 allele_1     MAF CALL_RATE HET_RATE
1  rs1000000    12    +       Y        A        G 0.12160   1.00000   0.2146
2 rs10000009     4    +       Y        G        A 0.07888   0.99762   0.1386

     HWP    RSQ  PHYS_POS A1 M1_FRQ M1_INFO M1_BETA  M1_SE    M1_P non_coded
1 1.0000 0.9817 125456933  A 0.1173  0.9452 -0.0113 0.0528 0.83090         G
2 0.1164 0.8354  71083542  A 0.9048  0.9017 -0.0097 0.0593 0.87000         G
```

Comment: Use ifelse() to define your conditions, you can nest them if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want non_coded to be one of two values:

```
Hy_MVA$non_coded <- Hy_MVA$allele_2
Hy_MVA$non_coded[Hy_MVA$allele_2 == Hy_MVA$A1] <- Hy_MVA$allele_1[Hy_MVA$allele_2 == Hy_MVA$A1]
```

That replaces values with allele_1 values in only the rows where allele_2 == A1. It sounds as though you might have a problem with ifelse converting a factor to a numeric.

Answer (score 2):

As Chase said, use `ifelse()`. I guess the code then becomes:

```
non_coded <- ifelse(allele_2 == A1, allele_1, allele_2)
```

## Edit

After seeing the updated question, it makes sense that you get numbers because `allele_1` and `allele_2` are factors. Adding a `as.character()` should fix this:

```
A1 <- c("A","A","B")
allele_1 <- as.factor(c("A","C","C"))
allele_2 <- as.factor(c("A","B","B"))

non_coded <- ifelse(allele_2 == A1, as.character(allele_1), as.character(allele_2))
non_coded 
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

Comment: I used the following code but got numerical values for non_coded instead of the string contents of allele_2 and allele_1                     Hy_MVA$non_coded <- ifelse(Hy_MVA$allele_2 == Hy_MVA$A1, Hy_MVA$allele_1, Hy_MVA$allele_2)

Comment: @rad - why don't you update your question with 1.) a `dput()` of the first few lines of your data.frame, and 2.) the code you've tried and the unexpected results you've gotten. It will be much easier to answer your question that way.